# Unable to cast base class to derived class with custom attribute

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert base type to derived type with "OfType().Cast().ToList()"

Here is my method

```
public class CosmosDBRepository<T> : ICosmosDBRepository<T> where T : class
    {
    public async Task<List<T>> GetSubscriptions<T, TE>(TE eventItem, params SubscriptionAction[] subscriptionAction)
                where T : Subscription
                where TE : Event
            {
                Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> predicate = (x) => x.EventType == eventItem.EventType
                                && x.IsActive;
    
                predicate = predicate.And(x => subscriptionAction.Contains(x.Action));
    
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventItem.PayerNumber))
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.PayerNumber == eventItem.PayerNumber);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventItem.AccountNumber))
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.AccountNumber == eventItem.AccountNumber);
                }
    
                var result = await GetItemsAsync(predicate, o => o.PayerNumber);
    
                return result.OfType<T>().Cast<T>().ToList();
            }
}
```

Base Class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class CosmoDBContainer : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    }

 [CosmoDBContainer(Name = "Subscription", PartitionKey = "PayerNumber")]
    public class Subscription
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", Order = 0)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Derived class:

```
[CosmoDBContainer(Name = "Subscription", PartitionKey = "PayerNumber")]
    public class CardBlockSubscription : Subscription
    {
        public override NotificationType NotificationType => NotificationType.CardBlock;
    }
```

Here is the calling method:

```
private async Task<List<CardBlockSubscription>> GetSubscriptions(CardBlockedEvent cardBlockedEvent)
        {
            var result = await _subscriptionRepository
                .GetSubscriptions<CardBlockSubscription,CardBlockedEvent>(cardBlockedEvent, SubscriptionAction.UiNotification);

            return result;
        }
```

Stack Trace:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__63`1.MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Is that bacause I am using custom attribute? that's why I am unable to type cast to derived class.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `OfType<T>` and `Cast<T>` would first take `T` only, and then do an extra cast to  `T` (although it's already only `T`) What data are you sending in, are they indeed `CardBlockSubscription`, or are they `Subscription`?

Comment: @Icepickle I have updated my question and added calling method also.

Comment: Another question might be, did you debug? And why not make `Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>>` more generic to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`?

Comment: i cannot do that because I already implemented concrete  class SubscriptionRepository : CosmosDBRepository<Subscription>

Comment: @Icepickle GetItemsAsync is a generic method which is in CosmosDBRepository<T> generic class.

Comment: So, are you getting an `InvalidCastException`? It does sound logical if you are first getting a concrete type of `Subscription` and you want to cast it to `CardBlockSubscription`. You can cast a base type into a derived type if it is a base type in the first place